# How to speed up PowerShell portscanner

Tags: multithreading, powershell, sockets

For various reasons, I started to write a PowerShell portscanner, not least to start learning it.

First iteration used `Test-Netconnection`. This seemed as if it would be too slow; so I went one level down to use sockets, specifically `System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient`. (Have started looking at `System.Net.Sockets.Socket` as the MS docs make mention of the `Socket.BeginConnect()` [method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.beginconnect?view=netframework-4.8#System_Net_Sockets_Socket_BeginConnect_System_Net_IPAddress_System_Int32_System_AsyncCallback_System_Object_) which can begin an asynchronous request for a remote connection, but not sure if this will help yet.)

This still seemed too slow, so I looked at jobs. All this did was consume more resources for not much speed increase, so after much googling, I managed to make threading (or what PowerShell calls threading any way) work through the use of `RunSpacePools`. I thought it was pretty much done, and performance is ok if you're looking at an input file of 5 IP addresses. However, tried it out with a CIDR /24 this morning, and it took about 20-30 minutes.

**[Edit]** I should add that this script will take a 'thread' value, but if none is provided uses a default thread value of `number of cores + 1` in order to take advantage of the RunSpacePool multithreading.

So I started looking at how Fyodor increased his speed, and in `The Art of Scanning` in [PHRACK article 11](http://www.textfiles.com/magazines/PHRACK/PHRACK51) he states (whilst talking about TCP Connect() scanning):

> While making a separate connect() call for every targeted port in a
>   linear fashion would take ages over a slow connection, you can hasten
>   the scan by using many sockets in parallel.

That is clearly where some optimisation is available.

So, is anyone able to point me in the direction of how I enable this - as I say, still quite new to PoSH, so am pushing the limits of my comprehension with `RunSpacePools`.
Specifically, I would like some advice on a) if my instincts are right to increase the scan speed to increase socket parallelism, b) how to do that and c) if `System.Net.Sockets.Socket` is more appropriate.

```
function doConnect {
    $ipLoopCount = 0
    $portLoopCount = 0
    # check for randomise switch
    if ($randomise) {
        $ipArray = makeRange | Sort-Object {Get-Random}
        $portArray = makePortRange | Sort-Object {Get-Random}
    } else {
        # Connects to IPs in order
        $ipArray = makeRange
        $portArray = makePortRange
    }
    # initialise runspaces
    if ($threads) {
        $useThreads = $threads
    } else {
        $useThreads = ([int]$env:NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS + 1)
    }
    $pool = [RunspaceFactory]::CreateRunspacePool(1, $useThreads)
    $pool.ApartmentState = "MTA"
    $pool.Open()
    $runspaces = @()
    # set higher priority for powershell process
    if ($priority) {
        $proc = Get-Process -Id $pid;
        $proc.PriorityClass = 'High'
    } else{
        $proc = Get-Process -Id $pid;
        $proc.PriorityClass = 'Normal'
    }

    # info object
    $infoDisplay = @{
        InputFile = $inFile
        Target_IPs = $ipArray
        Target_Ports = $portArray
        Process_Priority = $proc.PriorityClass
        Threads = $useThreads
    }
    [PSCustomObject]$infoDisplay
    # set up scriptblock to pass to runspaces
    $scriptblock = {
        Param (
            [IPAddress]$sb_ip,
            [int]$sb_port
        )
        # This progress bar doesn't work yet
        Write-Progress -Activity "Scan range $StartIPaddress - $EndIPAddress" -Status "% Complete:" -PercentComplete((($portLoopCount)/($ipArray.Length*$portArray.Length))*100)
        if ($delay) {
            $delay = Get-Random -Maximum 1000 -Minimum 1;
            Start-Sleep -m $delay
        }
        $socket = New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient
        $socket.Connect($sb_ip, $sb_Port)
        if ($socket.Connected) {
            Write-Output "Connected to $sb_port on $sb_ip"
        #} else {
        #    Write-Output "Failed to connect to port $sb_port on $sb_ip"
        }
        $socket.Close()
    }

    foreach ($nIP in $ipArray) {
        $ipLoopCount++
        foreach ($nPort in $portArray) {
            $portLoopCount++
            $runspace = [PowerShell]::Create()
            $null = $runspace.AddScript($scriptblock)
            $null = $runspace.AddArgument($nIP)
            $null = $runspace.AddArgument($nPort)
            $runspace.RunspacePool = $pool
            $runspaces += [PSCustomObject]@{
                Pipe = $runspace;
                Status = $runspace.BeginInvoke()
            }
        }
    }
    while ($runspaces.Status -ne $null) {
        $completed = $runspaces | Where-Object { $_.Status.IsCompleted -eq $true }
        foreach ($runspace in $completed) {
            $runspace.Pipe.EndInvoke($runspace.Status)
            $runspace.Status = $null
        }
    } 

    $pool.Close()
    $pool.Dispose()
}
```

It may be that PowerShell is entirely the wrong thing to attempt this in, but is a useful exercise as the environment is quite locked down, and installing a 'proper' portscanner - i.e. nmap - is impossible.

**[Edit 2]** I don't think reducing the timeout and plumbing that into the logic is the solutiuon that I'm after.

**[Edit 3]** The parallel switch didn't help.

**[Edit 4]** Have been thinking about Asynchronous socket connections, as this may help the overall connections speed - but then you have to have another thread/process looking after the incoming traffic. Unsure as to the efficacy.

Comment: Can you expand on exactly what you need help with? "am a bit stuck" is not very specific :)

Comment: Fair comment. Done!

Comment: Have you tried implementing the foreach -parallel in a workflow? Not sure how much speed it would give you, but worth a shot! https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psworkflow/about/about_foreach-parallel?view=powershell-5.1

Comment: `The '-parallel' parameter can be used only within a workflow`. I'm going to have to understand this concept, not come across it before. It seems pretty basic knowledge :/

Comment: Workflows tend to be reliable, but slow, so switching to a workflow is probably not the best option.

Comment: By the way @AnsgarWiechers thanks for the code edits. I've looked up the Code formatting principles for PoSH ( https://poshcode.gitbooks.io/powershell-practice-and-style/Style-Guide/Code-Layout-and-Formatting.html ) and edited my main script . It is much nicer, and I understand the removal of the semi-colons now. :)